# Update custom subview(uiview or web view) frame/size with the change in orientation-xcode 9+

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit

How to update the frame or size of subview/webview - created programmatically and added to a parent view which also contains a Navigation bar.
On orientation change the parent view resizes, but the subview does not.

I have this code in `viewdidload()`:

```
myView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

1) using this code if the app started in landscape mode as default the subview height is distorted in both orientation.

2) if app is started in portrait mode as default, this code works fine in changing to any orientation afterwards.

Please suggest some ideas in solving the first case.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what I came up with for custom webview to be added as subview:

1) In Main.storyboard, added navigation bar, then gave the following constraints and created outlet:
[image]
2) Here I have 2 ways to use constrains programmatically

- **First way:**

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit
class TestConstraintsViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
        @IBOutlet weak var myNavigationBar: UINavigationBar!
        var webView: WKWebView!
        var webConfiguration: WKWebViewConfiguration!

        override func loadView() {
            super.loadView()
            webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

            webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
            webView.uiDelegate = self
            webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            self.view.addSubview(webView)
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")
            let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
            webView.load(myRequest)

            //for leading trailing
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
                webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
                ])

            //for top/bottom layout
            if #available(iOS 11, *) {
                let safeLayoutGuide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: myNavigationBar.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
                    safeLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: webView.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0)
                    ])
            } else {
                let standardSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myNavigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: standardSpacing),
                    bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.bottomAnchor, constant: standardSpacing)
                    ])
            }
        }

        @IBAction func dismissView(_ sender: Any) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

- **Second way**

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit

class TestConstraintsViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myNavBar: UINavigationBar!
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var webConfiguration: WKWebViewConfiguration!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let safeAreaGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let myConstrainst = [
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: safeAreaGuide , attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myNavBar , attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: safeAreaGuide , attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: safeAreaGuide , attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        ]
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        self.view.addConstraints(myConstrainst)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

    @IBAction func dismissView(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using auto layout i would suggest using size classes to handle such changes. Since it is a huge concept i won't be able to explain it here but if you want to get more insights into it, watch [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/812/) video from wwdc 2017

Comment: thanks for replying, you meant to say auto layout in Interface builder?